# Locating points of a 2D image in a 3D point cloud

Tags: qt, opencv, qt-creator, vtk, pcl

greetings to all. I was wondering if anyone would know how to perform the following task:

Starting from an unstructured point cloud I was able to generate an image using the vtk point cloud viewer.

Once I have the image in openCV I perform a procedure to obtain landmarks and get as a result a collection of points in x, y coordinates (expressed in pixels).

What I need is to return those positions to the point cloud that is stored in a constructor of the PCL library:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud;
```

I am using Qt as a development tool and the QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget VTK viewer along with the PCLVisualizer.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you very much for everything

Comment: you need to know the projection and "look-at" transform you used to turn the cloud into a picture. then you can project those screen-space points back into the scene, as rays. how you intersect those rays with your point cloud, that can be a tricky question, because rays and points rarely intersect perfectly, so you'd need to give things some area/volume/tolerance.

Comment: When generating the image from the point cloud,is it possible to generate a second image where the color of the point is some index? E.g. first point is rendered in color (0,0,0) second point if (0,0,1), and so on...? Then you can just fetch the pixel position in that image,read the color and fetch the 3D point with that index?!?